# Start Windows in virtual machine from real hard drive partion

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machines

Is there any virtual machine under Linux which can start Windows (XP) from real hard drive partition, not from  emulation image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VMWare products can map physical disks to virtual disks, both on Linux and Windows:

http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/glossary_ws.html#wp1018930

> Physical disk
>
> — A hard disk in a virtual machine
>   that is mapped to a physical disk
>   drive or a partition of a drive on the
>   host machine. A physical disk is also
>   referred to as a raw disk. A virtual
>   machine's disk can be stored as a file
>   on the host file system (see Virtual
>   disk) or on a local hard disk. When a
>   virtual machine is configured to use a
>   physical disk, VMware Workstation
>   directly accesses the local disk or
>   partition as a physical device (not as
>   a file on a file system). It is
>   possible to boot a previously
>   installed operating system on an
>   existing partition within a virtual
>   machine environment. The only
>   limitation is that the existing
>   partition must reside on a local IDE
>   or SCSI drive.

Answer (score 3):

In xen you can use the device and give it directly to your guest.
You can use lvm:

```
disk        = [
                  'phy:/dev/volg1/thedisk,sda1,w',
                  'phy:/dev/volg1/theswap,sda2,w',
              ]
```

or directly a harddrve partition:

```
disk        = [
                  'phy:/dev/sda1,sda1,w',
              ]
```

you also can give a complete Disk to a guest, and let them partiton it:

```
disk        = [
                  'phy:/dev/sdb,sdb,w',
              ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Easier:
`sudo qemu /dev/sdX` will launch a virtual machine from an actual disk ;) qemu is free software, usually present in your distro's repositories

Answer (score 0):

KVM and Xen can both do it -- you just point the VM at the physical partition.

Comment: Xen is obsolete nowadays

Comment: My, aren't we the king of unsubstantiated assertions...